# Free implementation of "bounded priority queue" in C++

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I'm looking for a free software implementation of the *bounded priority queue* abstraction in C++. Basically, I need a data structure that will behave just like `std::priority_queue` but will at all times hold the "best" *n* elements at most.

Example:

```
std::vector<int> items; // many many input items
bounded_priority_queue<int> smallest_items(5);
for(vector<int>::const_iterator it=items.begin(); it!=items.end(); it++) {
  smallest_items.push(*it);
}
// now smallest_items holds the 5 smallest integers from the input vector
```

Does anyone know of a good implementation of such thing? Any experience with it?

Comment: I think this is covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933758/priority-queue-with-limited-space-looking-for-a-good-algorithm

Comment: Sigh, shopping questions never do not suck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the algorithm discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933758/priority-queue-with-limited-space-looking-for-a-good-algorithm) is probably what you are looking for. If you want to get a head start, you might want to consider building upon Boost's implementation `d_ary_heap_indirect` which is part of Boost.Graph (in `d_ary_heap.hpp`). If you do a good job with it, you might submit it to Boost. It could make a nice little addition, because such an implementation certainly has many uses.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a std::vector with a functor/comparison function and std::sort() it into the correct order?
The code is probably pretty trivial

Comment: That could perform significantly worse than a heap in certain cases.